# CSS :last-child:not(:only-child) not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

Currently, I have this selector:

```css
.form .mid td p:last-child:not(:only-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

It's not working as intended. I want to remove the margin ONLY if there are more than one `P` inside the `TD`

Comment: Seems work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XuKKB/ any chance you're using some other CSS that overwrites this?

Comment: indeed, in your example it's working, but not in my table. I've updated the code with my full selector

Comment: That doesn't make any difference: http://jsfiddle.net/XuKKB/1/ try to use devtools or firebug or similar inspection tools to see what styles are actually affecting your layout. E.g. I purposely unchecked "Normalized CSS" in jsfiddle, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: In which way does the code fail in your table? Not applied at all, or applied even when it shouldn’t? Note that browsers may have defaults that suppress margins of `p` elements inside table cells.

Comment: it is applied when it shouldn't. I'll try to update the code with my table. There isn't any CSS that is doing a reset or overwritting that selector, I've checked with firebug. The table is generated server side, i'll copy it using Firebug

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your `td` contains more than just `p` elements (I can't tell because you haven't shown your markup), you probably want to use `:last-of-type` and `:only-of-type` instead:

```css
.form .mid td p:last-of-type:not(:only-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```